# How do I build Monero for Windows from source?

Tags: monerod, source, build, compile, windows

Are there detailed build instructions for building Monero for Windows?

Does the version of Windows we are building for (7,8, 10) (x86 vs x64) require different dependencies?

edit: Can we compile Windows binaries in Linux? Or must we compile Monero using MinGW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is much harder to compile software for Windows than it is for GNU/Linux or MacOSX. Instructions do exist in [one of Ilya Kitaev's GitHub forks](//github.com/mbg033/monero-core/blob/9d79fdbeed31a7600c713ec80d98d6f507b5ee81/README.md#on-windows), but they haven't been merged yet at time of writing. They are copied (almost verbatim) below:

> #### On Windows:
>
> 1. Install [msys2](http://msys2.github.io/), follow the instructions on that page on how to update packages to the latest versions
> 2. Install monero dependencies as described in [monero documentation](https://github.com/monero-project/monero)
> 3. Install git:
>
>    ```
>    pacman -S git
>    ```
> 4. Install Qt5:
>
>    - if you need to build x86 application, install:
>
>      ```
>      pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-qt5
>      ```
>    - if you need to build x64 application, install:
>
>      ```
>      pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5
>      ```
> 5. Open `mingw` shell. MSYS2 will install start menu items for both mingw32 and mingw64 environments, so
>      you need to open appropriate one:
>      `%MSYS_ROOT%\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32` for x86 targed
>      or
>      `%MSYS_ROOT%\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64` for x64 targed
>
>    Where `%MSYS_ROOT%` will be `c:\msys32` if your host OS is x86-based or `c:\msys64` if your host OS
>      is x64-based
> 6. Clone git repository:
>
>    ```
>    git clone https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core.git
>    ```
> 7. Build the project:
>
>    ```
>    cd monero-core
>    ./build.sh
>    ```
> 8. Take result binary and dependencies in `./build/release/bin`
>
>    **important: if you testing application within VirtualBox virtual machine, make sure 3D acceleration is enabled
>      in machine's settings:
>
>      Machine > Settings > Display > [v] Enable 3D Acceleration**

Comment: All I've done to the instructions, at present, is to normalise the markdown.

Answer (score 7):

Detailed instructions about how to compile Monero on Windows can be found [here](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/README.md#compiling-monero).
If you are encountering problems compiling the x86 version try [this](https://forum.getmonero.org/5/support/2510/building-monero-v0-9-2-on-win32Monero) walkthrough.

The x86 version requires specialized x86 dependencies (on Windows).